# How to Import Amazon Affiliate Products in Wordpress without API?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-product-api, affiliate, aws-api-gateway

I want to import amazon affliate products with

Title
Image Thumbnail
Price
Price Label
Add to Cart
View Details
Rating
Review & Rating Number With Link
Amazon Product Link (Affiliate)

I dont want to use paid plugin like Wzone, Amazon Affiliate Shop, Affiliate Hub.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add Amazon Affiliated Ads to my Wordpress site via [Amazon Auto Links Plugin (free version)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-auto-links) and follow the installation instruction. Here is [my site](https://backtokokyou.com/) as an example.

[image]

**Caveat**: I am having a hard time getting it to be placed in my post directly with short code. As soon as you create a "unit by category", you should see some ads in your pages though. Just moving it to the right place it tricky and haven't figured that out yet.